# Como extrair informações de um vídeo ao fazer upload com FileUpload?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee, file-upload

nos sistema que estou fazendo preciso impedir que seja feito o upload de um vídeo com mais de 1 minuto e informar isso o usuário. Alguma forma de fazer isso? obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito com o [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/), que é uma biblioteca open source de manipulação de videos.

Exemplo de código:

```
public long getVideoDuration(String path){    
    private static final String filename = path; //EX.: "/home/videos/myvideo.mp4"
    IContainer container = IContainer.make();
    int result = container.open(filename, IContainer.Type.READ, null);
    return container.getDuration();
}
```

O exemplo completo deste código pode se visto [aqui](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/xuggler/inspect-a-video-file-with-xuggler/) e um tutorial sobre manipulação de video com Xuggler pode ser visto [aqui](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/introduction-xuggler-video-manipulation.html).